# Generate youtube thumbnail from embed code using php

Tags: php, youtube, joomla3.0

I have tried to strip the code below

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QUVdnzC19oU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

its working but not stripping the links properly all i get is

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/www.youtube.comembedQUVdnzC19oU/0.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/QUVdnzC19oU/0.jpg
```

Please find the php code below.

```
if(preg_match_all('@<iframe\s[^>]*src=[\"|\']([^\"\'\>]+)[^>].*?</iframe>@siu', $item->introtext, $iframesrc) >0){
            if(isset($iframesrc[1])){
                $vid = str_replace(
                    array(
                        'http://youtu.be/',
                        'http://www.youtube.com/embed/',
                        'http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/'), '', $iframesrc[1][0]);

                $vid = preg_replace('@\/.*?@i', '', $vid);

                if(!(empty($vid))){
                    $result = '' . 
                        '<div class="vimage">
                            <a class="video-link vlink" href="'.$item->link.'" title="">
                                <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$vid.'/0.jpg" />
                                <span class="play-icon">&nbsp;</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>';

                    $item->introtext = str_replace($iframesrc['0'], '', $item->introtext);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
array(
    'http://youtu.be/',
    'http://www.youtube.com/embed/',
    'http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/'), '', $iframesrc[1][0]);
```

by

```
array(
    '//youtu.be/',
    '//www.youtube.com/embed/',
    '//youtube.googleapis.com/v/',
    'http:', 'https:'), '', $iframesrc[1][0]);
```

The problem is that you URL das not start with `http://` as your code expects. My solution will work with `//`, `http://` and `https://`.

Also the following line is not useful, as it will never have any effect.

```
$vid = preg_replace('@\/.*?@i', '', $vid);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $url = "www.youtube.com/embed/QUVdnzC19oU";
  $urltokens = explode("/", $url);
  $vid_id = $urltokens[2];
  echo "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" . $vid_id . "/0.jpg";
?>
```

Considering you don't have http:// in the middle, this code will work.